# onError method of DecorationImage() in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image

Code works fine but because of my unreliable internet connection I am faced with an issue of NetworkImage.load ( See error image below )

```
Container(
 width: 60,
 height: 80,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.black12,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0))
  image: DecorationImage(
   image: NetworkImage(trend['imageUrl']),
   onError: <how we can handle this?>,
   fit: BoxFit.cover
  ),
 ),
);
```

I hope this issue can be fixed by handling it on onError method (Correct me if I'm wrong).  But I can't figure it out how to do that.

Error:
[image: Error I got on Android Studio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all lets say you intialize `NetworkImage` inside your class. like:

```
var imgVariable = NetworkImage(trend['imageUrl']);
```

Then, load your network image. If, error occurs then we will load from our assets to let user know that we could not load network image.

```
Container(
 width: 60,
 height: 80,
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.black12,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0))
  image: DecorationImage(
   image: imgVariable,
   onError: (errDetails){
       setState(){
           imgVariable = AssetImage('assets/could_not_load_img.jpg');
       };
   },
   fit: BoxFit.cover
  ),
 ),
);
```

Here, `assets/could_not_load_img.jpg` is image that is imformative sthg.

*Note: This may not seem to work with errors, but this can be a way I came up with. There are plugins like [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) to work beautifully on network images.

Comment: It gives me a cast error, becasue AssetImage istn' a NetworkImage. tried: `const AssetImage('assets/img/profile-bg3.jpg') as NetworkImage`, but gives CastError: `type 'AssetImage' is not a subtype of type 'NetworkImage' in type cast`

Answer (score 0):

so, onError in flutter basically takes a return type of function
it takes some error that may generate during the loading/fetching of the response **image URL** as the parameter `Error that is generated during call` and a report that provides information about `program subroutines` that can be found in the debug console as well

```
onError:(error, stackTrace) => AssetImage('assets/could_not_load_img.jpg'),
```

or you can check these
[click]https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78925#issuecomment-806553363

[click]https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78925

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution by Biplove doesn't seem to work anymore, at least I couldn't solve the resulting cast error when replacing the NetworkImage with an AssetImage. But a similar way would be:

```
class _YourClassState extends State<YourClass> {
 bool networkError = false;
 NetworkImage backgroundImage = const NetworkImage(
  'youUrl');
 AssetImage backgroundImageFallback = AssetImage('assets/img/....jpg');
 ...
 decoration: !networkError ? DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  onError: (Object e, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
                    log("Could not load the network image, showing fallback instead. Error: ${e.toString()}");
                    if (stackTrace != null) {
                      log(stackTrace.toString());
                    }
                    setState(() {
                      networkError = true;
                    });
                  },
                  image: backgroundImage) : 
                  DecorationImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  image: backgroundImageFallback)
                }
```