# The return type 'AssetImage' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I add error detection for a Decorated Network image? Specifically I cannot use regular `NetworkImage` due to the limitations when using in combination with `BoxDecoration` and `onError` not supporting what I need (`onError` should support another image being returned via Asset/Network/Icon).

```
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: 
                  //NetworkImage but fallback to local image if http request fails:
                      DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(mediaUrl!),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          onError: (exception, stackTrace) {
                            return AssetImage('assets/images/placeholder.jpg');
                          }
                      )
              ),
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49771765/flutter-default-image-to-image-network-when-it-fails does this help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [onError method of DecorationImage() in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63299583/onerror-method-of-decorationimage-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue and keep the circle decoration by wrapping the decoration inside of a `CachedNetworkImage` which already contains a good error catching method

```
  CachedNetworkImage(
                  imageUrl: userProfileImg!,
                  imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                    width: 60.0,
                    height: 60.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      image: DecorationImage(
                          image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                    ),
                  ),
                  placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.white,),
                  errorWidget: (context, exception, stackTrack) => Icon(Icons.person,color: Colors.grey,size: 35,),

              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use onError to log the error. See [DecorationImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/DecorationImage-class.html)

```
onError: (Object exception, StackTrace? stackTrace) {
  print('Image loading error: $exception, stack trace: $stackTrace');
}),
```

You can use [FadeInImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) to add a placeholder to an image

```
FadeInImage(
  placeholder: MemoryImage('assets/images/placeholder.jpg'),
  image: NetworkImage(mediaUrl!),
),
```